Why was Star Trek: Prodigy removed from Paramount?
Prodigy was removed from Paramount+. The reason given was that Paramount and a film company (I don't remember the name of) were combining with each other.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   So you have the answer to your question?  Are you saying you don't believe that reason?  Then why mention it?

@David I have the claimed answer from paramount. I mentioned that to prevent people from giving that as the answer and yes I'm saying I don't believe that reason.

If you don't believe the people who cancelled it, why would you believe other people instead?

@Valorum I would not I just want to know what other people think.

@LucasWinslow - Alas, we're not about opinion, we're about fact.

"They cancelled my favorite show! They gave a reason but I don't like it!! Give me a reason that I like. I won't like any reason you give me!!"

According to numerous articles around the web, Paramount cancelled Prodigy as a cost-cutting move, and then sold the rights to Netflix.
For example, this Deadline article.  There are numerous other sources for the same story cited by the Wikipedia article for the show.

I knew that but it was very popular among kids and older and current star trek fans. Making them a lot of money. Meaning why would it be a cost-cutting move.

Clearly it was costing then more than it was making. Plus they have to pay residuals forever, so it doesn't stop bleeding money even after it's made it onto streaming.

@Valorum that is nearly impossible that is like saying that is why tos was cancelled.

But that is why TOS was cancelled?  It was fairly well-received, but its ratings weren't high enough to bring in enough revenue to offset the production costs.

@David fair enough I forgot about the that sorry.

Kids don't pay the bills and they have little enough influence on whether their parents subscribe to Paramount Plus.

@Valorum true kids are kids they have no bills to pay. They do have little influence but at least they have influence.

@LucasWinslow - I have said it before. The priorities of the streaming providers are very different from the priorities of network television makers. A show can be woefully poorly received by audiences and get multiple seasons as long as it is driving initial subscriptions. By comparison, a network TV show that has terrible ratings will always be cancelled, regardless of positive fan reaction
